# Spawn System in Unity, Destroying Spwans

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, null, spawn

I'm making a spawn system for my game, that spawns enemies at random positions, but Unity is telling me that I'm not checking if the object is already destroyed. I've tried to solve it with some other topics here but I couldn't do it.
Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySpawn : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Enemy2Spawn;
    public float maxWidth;
    public float minWidth;
    public float rateSpwan;
    private float currentRSpawn = 2.0f;
    public int maxInimigo;
    public int Inimigos = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(0, 6.03f, 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (currentRSpawn > Time.time & Inimigos<=maxInimigo)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(minWidth, maxWidth), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            Instantiate(Enemy2Spawn);
            currentRSpawn = currentRSpawn + rateSpwan;
            Inimigos++;
        }

        if (Enemy2Spawn. == null)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> "The object of type 'GameObject' has been already destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Update` function, you are checking if the `GameObject` is null, which means that it does not exist, then you are using `Destroy()` to destroy that object that **does not exist**. Instead, you will want to check if the object exists in the if statement that spawns the enemies. Add that to the if statement, like this, and you should be good.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySpawn : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Enemy2Spawn;
    public float maxWidth;
    public float minWidth;
    public float rateSpwan;
    private float currentRSpawn = 2.0f;
    public int maxInimigo;
    public int Inimigos = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(0, 6.03f, 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (currentRSpawn > Time.time && Inimigos <= maxInimigo && Enemy2Spawn == null)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(minWidth, maxWidth), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            Instantiate(Enemy2Spawn);
            currentRSpawn = currentRSpawn + rateSpwan;
            Inimigos++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a couple things that seem off on this script:

**before that**: For the error if you set `Enemy2Spawn` to an object in the scene and it gets destroyed then the value is null then when it tries to Instantiate again, which causes the error (could put the condition "`Enemy2Spawn != null`" in the first if statement as a fix)

"`transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(minWidth, maxWidth), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);`"
This line changes the object attached to the script, it's position to be exact, which won't affect the position of the enemy you are going to spawn.

"Instantiate(Enemy2Spawn);" makes a clone of the variable's value. The clone inherits all values of the original, so position will be what the original's position is.

Unless you didn't set the value of "`Enemy2Spawn`" it would not become null, unless a different script changes the value and that it is a prefab. So, "`if (Enemy2Spawn == null)`" assuming the value is set, does not change else where and is set as a prefab in this case then the statement is never true. If the statement ever became true the line inside "`Destroy(this.gameObject);`" destroys the object that the script is attached to so it seems counter productive to me (to destroy the spawner) but if it's a measure to prevent error it should be in the Start or Awake function or if setting it with a different script just destroy the script instead of setting the variable to null (which i really doubt though).

Here is a changed script that should fix the issues i stated and fit your needs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collection.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySpawn : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Enemy2Spawn;
    public float maxWidth;
    public float minWidth;
    public float rateSpwan;
    private float currentRSpawn = 2.0f;
    public int maxInimigo;
    public int Inimigos = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(0, 6.03f, 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (currentRSpawn > Time.time & Inimigos<=maxInimigo)
        {
            Instantiate(Enemy2Spawn, new Vector3(Random.Range(minWidth, maxWidth), transform.position.y, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
            currentRSpawn = currentRSpawn + rateSpwan;
            Inimigos++;
        }
    }
}
```

Different reason for the error, the given script may spit out the error but i don't see how it'd cause it so it would have to be caused by a different script that causes the object with the script attached to be destroyed just before executing the update function.

Also, the scripting API suggests calling Destroy like the following if using JS/unityscript

UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(this.gameObject);

I hope this helps, if not then more information is needed